# How do I get fixed footer to stick to bottom of div after scrolling past a threshold?

Tags: css, position, footer, sticky

I'm trying to get the `footer` element to act as a `position: fixed` tag (displaying over all content) until I scroll to the end of the container `div` after which it's supposed to go back to it's default state. There are implementations for top nav elements but I haven't been able to figure this one out even after several tries at writing a function to fire on scroll events.
Here's my pen: https://codepen.io/azdravkovski/pen/VXEEwE?editors=1111

Thanks.

Comment: You want to implement sticky footer?

Comment: Yes, but I can't use ```position: sticky``` because I need to support IE.

Comment: NO i am saying you want fixed footer right

Comment: I'm saying I want the footer to be fixed while scrolling up to a point and then just re-enter the flow after it touches the bottom of its container.